# How to get my project featured on the main page of threejs

Tags: three.js

What do I need to do to get the project to the threejs.org homepage? I want to understand what criteria you need to have for placement and how the whole procedure works in general.

I tried writing mrdoob, but I don't have direct access to write a post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the first step is submitting a project [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/c/showcase/7), and then hope your project gets selected. The homepage itself is updated [a few times a year](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/about-the-showcase-category/25)